# Using timespan for values above 60 minutes

Tags: formatting, timespan

I'm using timespan to convert decimal to time in C#

TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59.42).ToString("mm\:ss"); which outputs 59:25. However I want to handle minutes above 60 for example:

TimeSpan.FromMinutes(62.87).ToString("mm\:ss") for which I want to output as 62:52 but what I get is 02.52.

Is there a way this can be handled by .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the TimeSpan you want, you just aren't displaying it properly.

The "mm" term in the format string gives the Minutes property (always in the range 0-59) and not the TotalMinutes property (the total number of minutes in the TimeSpan).

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(62.8);
string output = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 
     // Display the total minutes, throwing away the fractional portion.
     (int) ts.TotalMinutes, 
     // Display the seconds component (0-59) as two digits with a leading
     // zero if necessary.
     ts.Seconds.ToString("D2"));
```